# Import Error: cannot import name 'playsound' from 'playsound'

Tags: python, python-playsound

I am trying to set up my Raspberry Pi Zero to play a sound through a pimoroni audio board. I am trying to use playsound but keep getting the message `"Import Error: cannot import name 'playsound' from 'playsound'"`. My program is a simple one using Python 3.7.3:

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound('file.mp3')
```

As suggested in a similar post, I have deleted Python 2.7 and loaded (reloaded) Python 3.7.3. I have tried uninstalling playsound and have loaded playsound using pip3. Pip3 list tells me I have playsound 1.2.2 loaded.
I do not know what else to try.

Comment: Do you have a file named `playsound.py` in the current directory?

Comment: The file with the program in it is called playsound.py.

Comment: I changed the name of the program file to noise.py and the error message goes away. HOWEVER no sound is played!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, rolling back to an older version of playsound helps. You can do this by typing the following in the command prompt:

```
pip install playsound==1.2.2
```

Here, 1.2.2 stands for the version of playsound to which you will be rolling back.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is downgrade your playsound to any other version.

Comment: This is already covered by another answer, can you provide additional information?